# Swagger-ui does not display my minimum and maximum values for the "limit" query parm?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

Here is how the JSON object looks like and I can not get maximum and minimum values for the limit query part displayed:

```
        "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "limit",
        "in": "query",
       "description": "How many items to return at one time (max 100)",
        "minimum": 0,
        "maximum": 63333,
        "required": false,
        "type": "integer",
        "format": "int32"
      }
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue with Swagger-UI ([possibly you located the same issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1217)?).

However, I tried it using [ReDoc](https://rebilly.github.io/ReDoc/) and it properly rendered the min/max of the range.